# Deleting List With One Node In C

Tags: c, pointers, sortedlist

I have a function here that will remove a node from a sorted list of any type. 
I am having difficulties with one specific case: when there is 1 node in the list and you want to delete it.

In this case, I want to make the list empty, so when the list is printed out, no data is printed to the screen, but I can't seem to get that result. Just say, for example, the list is of type double, and the list consists of just one node 2.0. If this node is the target for deletion, the proceeding output should be an empty list. Instead my code prints out 0.0.

I am not sure how to handle this error. I have found the specific part of the function where this is to be taken care of, but its implementation escapes me. I first check if the previous node is null, and then check if the list length is equal to 1.

The function returns 1 if it was successful and 0 if it failed.

```
 int SLRemove(SortedListPtr list, void *newObj) {

   Node ptr, iterptr, prev = NULL;

   if(list==NULL || newObj ==NULL) {
      return 0;
   }

   int size= listlength(list);

   for(ptr=list->start; ptr!=NULL; ptr=ptr->next) {
     if(list->cf(newObj, ptr->info)==0){//found matching entry in list
       //deleting first node;
       if(prev==NULL) {
         if(size == 1) {
            printf("attempting to delete list with 1 node\n");
            /*code to delete node where it's the only element in the ist, should make the list empty.*/
            return 1;
         }

         list->start = ptr->next;
         destroyNode(ptr);
         return 1;
       } else {
         prev->next = ptr->next;
         destroyNode(ptr);
         return 1;
       }
    }
    prev = ptr;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, is there another way to accomplish this without changing the function parameters?

Comment: Sorry for not completely following the logic, I'm still a bit new to C and I've been staring at this issue for hours. Maybe it would help if someone could explain to me why I'm getting this error in the first place? I still don't fully understand when I try to delete a list with one node, I get 0.0 as the result instead of the empty list.

Comment: @Chad - it would help to see the definitions for SortedListPtr, Note, ... .

Comment: "I get 0.0 as the result instead of the empty list." You have to show the part of the code  that prints that if you want us to comment on it. What rcgldris saying is that `list->start` should be set to NULL when the last node is deleted. So any code that uses the list needs only to check for that. If you think you are already doing that and am still getting incorrect results please show the code that is attempting to use the empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first check should be:

```
   if(list==NULL || list->start == NULL || newObj ==NULL) {
      return 0;
   }
```

Once past this check, there's at least one node in the list. If prev == NULL, then you need to set list->start = list->start->next to delete the first node. It doesn't matter if there is one node or more than one node.

The other functions you have need to check for list->start == NULL (or size == 0) to avoid printing garbage.

Using a double pointer can eliminate checking for prev == NULL, but I can't explain for your code since I don't know how node is defined, and it's not really needed, since checking for prev == NULL is just as good. As an example:

```
typedef struct Node_{
    struct Node_ *next;
    ...
}Node;

/* in the delete function */
Node **ppNode = &list->start; /* ptr to list->start or ...->next */

/* to advance ppNode */
ppNode = &(*ppNode->next);

/* to remove a node from the list */
*ppNode = (*ppNode)->next;
```